# What's the formal term for the "Group of points that have X as their neighbor"?

Tags: clustering, k-nearest-neighbour

Due to asymetrical nature of K-NN, the points neighboring X need not be the same as the points which have X as their neighbor.

Is there a formal term to designate those points which have X as one of their neighbors, from the perspective of X?

X's neighborhood?

Points adjacent to X?

X's locality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this called **reverse kNN** or inverse kNN in literature.

> F. Korn and S. Muthukrishnan: Influence Sets Based on Reverse Nearest Neighbor Queries. SIGMOD 2000

Not sure how common it is, though. Seems a superficial concept to me.